# R dpylr select_if with multiple conditions

Tags: r, select, dplyr

I would like to select all numeric variables as well as some variables by name.  I have managed to use select_if to get the numeric variables and select to get the ones by name but can't combine the two into one statement

```
x = data.table(c(1,2,3),c(10,11,12),c('a','b','c'),c('x','y','z'), c('l', 'm','n'))
```

I want my result to be:

```
V1 V2 V4 V5
1 10  x l
2 11  y m
3 12  z n
```

I tried this but it doesn't work

```
y = x %>%
select_if(is.numeric, V4, V5)
```

Comment: str(x) shows that all columns are in character. I think this is a potential reason for the error? I also wonder if you can use column names directly.

Comment: What's the purpose of `cbind`? Just use `data.table`. Using `cbind`, everything is coerced to a `character` matrix and so every column is `character`. If you define `x` as `data.table(c(1,2,3),c(10,11,12),c('a','b','c'),c('x','y','z'), c('l', 'm','n'))`, then `x %>% select_if(is.numeric)` works (what's the purpose of `V4` and `V5` in `select_if`?)

Comment: @nicola What makes you think OP did a mistake in his packages ? `dtplyr` encompass `data.table` as far as I can tell. Your edit conflit with author intent IMO.

Comment: @Tensibai Ops, I didn't know `dtplyr` and thought OP made a typo.

Comment: @nicola No problem for me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If we have a data frame, `x`:

```
x = data.frame(V1=c(1,2,3),V2=c(10,11,12),V3=c('a','b','c'),V4=c('x','y','z'),V5=c('l', 'm','n'), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
##  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
##1  1 10  a  x  l
##2  2 11  b  y  m
##3  3 12  c  z  n
```

where `V1` and `V2` are actually `numeric` and the rest of the columns are not factors, then we can do:

```
library(dplyr)
y <- x %>% select_if(function(col) is.numeric(col) | 
                                   all(col == .$V4) | 
                                   all(col == .$V5))
##  V1 V2 V4 V5
##1  1 10  x  l
##2  2 11  y  m
##3  3 12  z  n
```

Not saying that this is the best thing to do, but it does do what you want. The issue here is that `select_if` expects its function to return a boolean vector corresponding to all columns.

Another way is to use `select`:

```
y <- x %>% select(which(sapply(.,class)=="numeric"),V4,V5)
##  V1 V2 V4 V5
##1  1 10  x  l
##2  2 11  y  m
##3  3 12  z  n
```

which is probably better.

Comment: This has a nasty side effect. `all(col %in% .$V4)` is not equivalent to `col` actually being `.$V4`. `all(col == .$V4)` might be a better option.

Comment: @AlexR: Thanks. I'll make the change. However, I think that my whole answer with `select_if` has a nasty side effect :-)

Comment: Is using `select_at` a better alternative?

Comment: only slightly shorter on the last option: 
x %>% select(c(which(sapply(., is.numeric)), "V4", "V5"))

Comment: @HNSKD Any idea how this could be done with `select_at` ?

Comment: @RafaelToledo:  x %>% select_at(vars(names(.)[sapply(., is.numeric)], "V4", "V5"))

Answer (score 5):

One option with `map` (from `purrr`)

```
library(purrr)
x %>%
     map2(names(x), ~.[is.numeric(.x)|.y != "V3"])  %>%
     Filter(length, .) %>% 
     bind_cols
 #     V1    V2    V4    V5
 #  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>
 #1     1    10     x     l
 #2     2    11     y     m
 #3     3    12     z     n
```

Or as @RoyalTS suggested

```
x %>% 
    imap( ~ .[is.numeric(.x)|.y != "V3"]) %>%
    keep(~length(.x) > 0) %>%
    bind_cols
```

---

As the dataset is a `data.table`, the option for subsetting `data.table` would be

```
x[, sapply(x, is.numeric) | colnames(x) != "V3", with = FALSE]
#   V1 V2 V4 V5
#1:  1 10  x  l
#2:  2 11  y  m
#3:  3 12  z  n
```

#### data

```
x <- data.table(c(1,2,3),c(10,11,12),c('a','b','c'),c('x','y','z'), 
              c('l', 'm','n'))
```

NOTE: @nicola mentioned about why `cbind` is not required.  So, we are not describing the same issues that was already raised.

Comment: @RonakShah You are right.  I could have used `colnames(x) %in% c("V4", "V5")` but I thought `"V3"` would make it short

Comment: @RonakShah Yes sir, you are right.  In that case `%in% c("V4", "V5")` should be the way to go.

Comment: These days you could replace the `map2(names(x), ~.[is.numeric(.x)|.y != "V3"])` with `imap(~.[is.numeric(.x)|.y != "V3"])`.

Answer (score -1):

use data.frame function:

```
x = data.frame(V1=c(1,2,3),V2=c(10,11,12),V3=c('a','b','c'),V4=c('x','y','z'),V5=c('l', 'm','n'))
```

then  `x %>% select_if(is.numeric)` works.