# Select columns based on multiple attribute conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to figure how to efficiently select columns using `dplyr::select_if`. The `starwars` data set in dplyr 0.70 is a good dataset to use for this:

```
> starwars
# A tibble: 87 x 13
                 name height  mass    hair_color  skin_color eye_color birth_year gender homeworld species     films  vehicles starships
                <chr>  <int> <dbl>         <chr>       <chr>     <chr>      <dbl>  <chr>     <chr>   <chr>    <list>    <list>    <list>
 1     Luke Skywalker    172    77         blond        fair      blue       19.0   male  Tatooine   Human <chr [5]> <chr [2]> <chr [2]>
 2              C-3PO    167    75          <NA>        gold    yellow      112.0   <NA>  Tatooine   Droid <chr [6]> <chr [0]> <chr [0]>
 3              R2-D2     96    32          <NA> white, blue       red       33.0   <NA>     Naboo   Droid <chr [7]> <chr [0]> <chr [0]>
 4        Darth Vader    202   136          none       white    yellow       41.9   male  Tatooine   Human <chr [4]> <chr [0]> <chr [1]>
 5        Leia Organa    150    49         brown       light     brown       19.0 female  Alderaan   Human <chr [5]> <chr [1]> <chr [0]>
 6          Owen Lars    178   120   brown, grey       light      blue       52.0   male  Tatooine   Human <chr [3]> <chr [0]> <chr [0]>
 7 Beru Whitesun lars    165    75         brown       light      blue       47.0 female  Tatooine   Human <chr [3]> <chr [0]> <chr [0]>
 8              R5-D4     97    32          <NA>  white, red       red         NA   <NA>  Tatooine   Droid <chr [1]> <chr [0]> <chr [0]>
 9  Biggs Darklighter    183    84         black       light     brown       24.0   male  Tatooine   Human <chr [1]> <chr [0]> <chr [1]>
10     Obi-Wan Kenobi    182    77 auburn, white        fair blue-gray       57.0   male   Stewjon   Human <chr [6]> <chr [1]> <chr [5]>
```

Now say that I would like select columns that are only integers. This works well:

```
library(dplyr)

starwars %>%
  select_if(is.numeric)
```

But what should I do if I want to select based on multiple criteria. For example maybe I want both numeric and character columns:

```
starwars %>%
  select_if(c(is.numeric, is.character))
```

Or maybe I want all numeric AND the `name` column:

```
starwars %>%
  select_if(name, is.character)
```

Neither of the two examples above work so I am wondering how I might accomplish what I've outlined here.

Comment: Related question and answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39592879/r-dpylr-select-if-with-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elegant tidyverse syntax where `~` stands for anonymous function may be helpful when using `select_if` function:

```
require(tidyverse)

# numeric and character columns
starwars %>% select_if(~ is.numeric(.) | is.character(.)) 

# all numeric AND the name column
starwars %>% select(name, where(is.numeric))
```

Predicate functions e.g. `is.numeric` inside of `select` for some reason is recommended to be wrapped in `where()` according to tidyverse creators.

Answer (score 5):

For the first example:

```
starwars %>%
  select_if(function(col) {is.numeric(col) | is.character(col)})
```

This is taken directly from the [RDocumentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.5.0/topics/select_if) page.

For the second:

```
toKeep <- sapply(starwars, is.numeric)
starwars %>%
  select("name", names(toKeep)[as.numeric(toKeep) == 1])
```

I cannot make something prettier up at the moment, but I'm sure there is a better way :)

Comment: Indeed right there on RDocumentation though this doesn't answer the all numeric AND `name` column question. Any thoughts there?

Comment: One option: starwars %>% group_by(name) %>% select_if(is.numeric). But that's a bit ugly.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that took a little longer than I thought. See updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

From version 1.0.0, as mentioned in the [news](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/NEWS.md),

> select() and rename() use the latest version of the tidyselect interface. Practically, this means that you can now combine selections using Boolean logic (i.e. !, & and |), and use predicate functions (e.g. is.character) to select variables by type (#4680).

```r
### Install development version on GitHub first until CRAN version is available
# install.packages("devtools")
# devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

starwars %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  glimpse()
#> Rows: 87
#> Columns: 14
#> $ name       <chr> "Luke Skywalker", "C-3PO", "R2-D2", "Darth Vader", "Leia...
#> $ height     <int> 172, 167, 96, 202, 150, 178, 165, 97, 183, 182, 188, 180...
#> $ mass       <dbl> 77.0, 75.0, 32.0, 136.0, 49.0, 120.0, 75.0, 32.0, 84.0, ...
#> $ hair_color <chr> "blond", NA, NA, "none", "brown", "brown, grey", "brown"...
#> $ skin_color <chr> "fair", "gold", "white, blue", "white", "light", "light"...
#> $ eye_color  <chr> "blue", "yellow", "red", "yellow", "brown", "blue", "blu...
#> $ birth_year <dbl> 19.0, 112.0, 33.0, 41.9, 19.0, 52.0, 47.0, NA, 24.0, 57....
#> $ sex        <chr> "male", "none", "none", "male", "female", "male", "femal...
#> $ gender     <chr> "masculine", "masculine", "masculine", "masculine", "fem...
#> $ homeworld  <chr> "Tatooine", "Tatooine", "Naboo", "Tatooine", "Alderaan",...
#> $ species    <chr> "Human", "Droid", "Droid", "Human", "Human", "Human", "H...
#> $ films      <list> [<"The Empire Strikes Back", "Revenge of the Sith", "Re...
#> $ vehicles   <list> [<"Snowspeeder", "Imperial Speeder Bike">, <>, <>, <>, ...
#> $ starships  <list> [<"X-wing", "Imperial shuttle">, <>, <>, "TIE Advanced ...
```

To select either numeric or character columns:

```r
starwars %>%
  select(is.numeric | is.character) %>% 
  glimpse()
#> Rows: 87
#> Columns: 11
#> $ height     <int> 172, 167, 96, 202, 150, 178, 165, 97, 183, 182, 188, 180...
#> $ mass       <dbl> 77.0, 75.0, 32.0, 136.0, 49.0, 120.0, 75.0, 32.0, 84.0, ...
#> $ birth_year <dbl> 19.0, 112.0, 33.0, 41.9, 19.0, 52.0, 47.0, NA, 24.0, 57....
#> $ name       <chr> "Luke Skywalker", "C-3PO", "R2-D2", "Darth Vader", "Leia...
#> $ hair_color <chr> "blond", NA, NA, "none", "brown", "brown, grey", "brown"...
#> $ skin_color <chr> "fair", "gold", "white, blue", "white", "light", "light"...
#> $ eye_color  <chr> "blue", "yellow", "red", "yellow", "brown", "blue", "blu...
#> $ sex        <chr> "male", "none", "none", "male", "female", "male", "femal...
#> $ gender     <chr> "masculine", "masculine", "masculine", "masculine", "fem...
#> $ homeworld  <chr> "Tatooine", "Tatooine", "Naboo", "Tatooine", "Alderaan",...
#> $ species    <chr> "Human", "Droid", "Droid", "Human", "Human", "Human", "H...
```

Or select non-list columns

```r
starwars %>%
  select(!is.list) %>% 
  glimpse()
#> Rows: 87
#> Columns: 11
#> $ name       <chr> "Luke Skywalker", "C-3PO", "R2-D2", "Darth Vader", "Leia...
#> $ height     <int> 172, 167, 96, 202, 150, 178, 165, 97, 183, 182, 188, 180...
#> $ mass       <dbl> 77.0, 75.0, 32.0, 136.0, 49.0, 120.0, 75.0, 32.0, 84.0, ...
#> $ hair_color <chr> "blond", NA, NA, "none", "brown", "brown, grey", "brown"...
#> $ skin_color <chr> "fair", "gold", "white, blue", "white", "light", "light"...
#> $ eye_color  <chr> "blue", "yellow", "red", "yellow", "brown", "blue", "blu...
#> $ birth_year <dbl> 19.0, 112.0, 33.0, 41.9, 19.0, 52.0, 47.0, NA, 24.0, 57....
#> $ sex        <chr> "male", "none", "none", "male", "female", "male", "femal...
#> $ gender     <chr> "masculine", "masculine", "masculine", "masculine", "fem...
#> $ homeworld  <chr> "Tatooine", "Tatooine", "Naboo", "Tatooine", "Alderaan",...
#> $ species    <chr> "Human", "Droid", "Droid", "Human", "Human", "Human", "H...
```

To select `name` & character columns

```r
starwars %>%
  select(name | is.character) %>% 
  glimpse()
#> Rows: 87
#> Columns: 8
#> $ name       <chr> "Luke Skywalker", "C-3PO", "R2-D2", "Darth Vader", "Leia...
#> $ hair_color <chr> "blond", NA, NA, "none", "brown", "brown, grey", "brown"...
#> $ skin_color <chr> "fair", "gold", "white, blue", "white", "light", "light"...
#> $ eye_color  <chr> "blue", "yellow", "red", "yellow", "brown", "blue", "blu...
#> $ sex        <chr> "male", "none", "none", "male", "female", "male", "femal...
#> $ gender     <chr> "masculine", "masculine", "masculine", "masculine", "fem...
#> $ homeworld  <chr> "Tatooine", "Tatooine", "Naboo", "Tatooine", "Alderaan",...
#> $ species    <chr> "Human", "Droid", "Droid", "Human", "Human", "Human", "H...
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: if you are going to do this you likely should include install instructions until the version is on CRAN.

Answer (score 2):

You can either write your own function:

```
 to_keep <- function(x) is.numeric(x) | is.character(x)
 starwars %>% select_if(to_keep)
```

or you can use "quosure-style lambda functions":

```
starwars %>% select_if(funs(is.numeric(.) | is.character(.)))
```

I don't know of a good way of combining different logic for column selection, so I'd use an hybrid approach (even if it's not very elegant as you have to repeat the initial dataset):

```
 starwars %>%
    select("name") %>%
    bind_cols(select_if(starwars, funs(is.numeric(.) | is.character(.))))
```

Comment: Any thought how I could select name and all column with numeric data?

Answer (score 0):

For the second part (getting the numeric AND the name column):

```
to_keep <- c(starwars %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% names,"name")
starwars %>% select(one_of(to_keep))
```