# How to select non-numeric columns using dplyr::select_if

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to select all columns that are not numeric. I can select all numeric columns easily using `select_if`:

```
mtcars %>% select_if(is.numeric)
```

What if I want to select `non-numeric` columns? I tried:

```
mtcars %>% select_if(!is.numeric)
```

But I got error message below:

```
Error in !is.numeric : invalid argument type
```

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Take a look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39592879/r-dpylr-select-if-with-multiple-conditions

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can use `purrr`'s `negate()` which is included if you use `library(tidyverse)` rather than just `library(dplyr)`

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% select_if(negate(is.numeric))
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use a purrr-style anonymous function, provided you have a reasonably recent version of dplyr:

```r
library(dplyr)

iris %>% select_if(~!is.numeric(.x)) %>% head()
#>   Species
#> 1  setosa
#> 2  setosa
#> 3  setosa
#> 4  setosa
#> 5  setosa
#> 6  setosa
```

or the old-style `funs` notation still works, e.g.

```r
iris %>% select_if(funs(!is.numeric(.))) %>% head()
#>   Species
#> 1  setosa
#> 2  setosa
#> 3  setosa
#> 4  setosa
#> 5  setosa
#> 6  setosa
```

Comment: fantastic - even though @MrFlick 's solution works, I love that this solution more because you don't need to load another library. Just a tiny thing: the above code also works using the dot `(.)` instead of `(.x)` as in `iris %>% select_if(~!is.numeric(.))`

Comment: Yeah, I use `.x` in purrr-style functions because it's easier to differentiate from using `.` to tell the pipes where to place the data.

Comment: Oh, I see, I thought you must use the dplyr syntax for the piped object. Didn't know about the purr-style pipe identifier, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution could be:

```
df[, !(names(df) %in% names(df %>% select_if(is.numeric)))]

Example:
df <- data.frame(
  name = c( "a", "b", "c", "d" ),
  last_name = c( "r", "t", "s", "b" ),
  x = c( 3, 2, 1, 2 ),
  y = c( 4, 3, 4, 3 ),
  z = c( 8, 9, 6, 7 ) , stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> df[, !(names(df) %in% names(df %>% select_if(is.numeric)))]
#  name last_name
#1    a         r
#2    b         t
#3    c         s
#4    d         b
```