# How do I remove all integer columns from a dataframe in R with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to remove all integer columns from my dataframe utilizing dplyr leaving only non-integer numeric columns. I thought I would be able to do like with the below:

Note: I realize I can select the numerics in my example below, but my actual dataset has other variable types in addition to numeric and integer.

```
library(dplyr)
mydata <- USArrests

mydata2 <- mydata %>% 
  select(!is.integer)
```

but that gives the error:

> Error in !is.integer : invalid argument type

```
mydata2 <- mydata %>% 
  select(-is.integer)
```

Errors out with:

> Error in -x : invalid argument to unary operator

The following works, but I'd like to know how to do this in dplyr as well.

```
mydata_temp <- mydata[, sapply(mydata, function(x) !is.integer(x))]
mydata_numeric_vars <- mydata_temp %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric)
```

Any suggestions? Seems like this should be fairly straightforward in dplyr but in looking around stack I can't seem to find a similar Q/A for this?

Comment: Use `select_if(!is.integer)`

Comment: You should look here: [How to select non-numeric columns using dplyr::select_if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48430882/how-to-select-non-numeric-columns-using-dplyrselect-if)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `select_if`

```
out <- mydata %>%
           select_if(Negate(is.integer))
str(out)
#'data.frame':  50 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ Murder: num  13.2 10 8.1 8.8 9 7.9 3.3 5.9 15.4 17.4 ...
# $ Rape  : num  21.2 44.5 31 19.5 40.6 38.7 11.1 15.8 31.9 25.8 ...
```

If we want to select more than one type, then use

```
mydata %>% 
   select_if(~ !(is.integer(.x)) | is.numeric(.x))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, so is there a way to combine that in one select_if statement to select numerics too or does that require two select statements like:  kiva_numeric_vars <- kiva %>% select_if(Negate(is.integer)) %>%  select_if(is.numeric)

Comment: @RussThomas  Try `mydata %>% select_if(~ !(is.integer(.x)) | is.numeric(.x))`

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51358388/how-to-select-if-in-dplyr-where-the-logical-condition-is-negated) by @astaines led me to this alternative as well:  mydata %>%  select_if(funs(!is.integer(.) & is.numeric(.))) %>%  head()

Comment: @RussThomas  You can either wrap it in `funs` or use `~`

Answer (score 3):

a possible workaround:

```
mydata %>% 
  .[ , !sapply(., is.integer)]
```